# How to fetch email from userid in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a list of entries in a table with `userId`. Now I want to loop them and show the email for every userId.

I have tried the `@Membership.GetUser(2).Email` but nothing I do seems to work.

Im using webmatrix with asp.net 4 and razor.

What to do?

/mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be pulling the emails in your view. You should get the emails in your Controller and pass them to your view.

In Controller you can get get user by id using [Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx) method and then get the email using the [Email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.email.aspx) property

Answer (score 0):

This would return the email of each user to the view -

```
@foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{ 
  <p>Email: @user.Email</p>
}
```